# 2 ways of looking at $\nabla \cdot \vec r $, different answer?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I would like to calculate $\nabla \cdot \vec r $. I can think of 2 methods to do this, but they give different results strangely. Can someone help me out?

$$\nabla \cdot \vec r =\nabla_r \cdot \vec r  =\frac{\partial }{\partial r}  \hat r\cdot r \hat r= \hat r \cdot \hat r=1$$, in which $\hat r$ a unit vector

$$\nabla \cdot \vec r =(\frac{\partial }{\partial x},\frac{\partial }{\partial y},\frac{\partial }{\partial z} ) \cdot(x,y,z) =1+1+1=3$$

The 2nd method is true by def., but what is wrong with the first method?

Comment: second one is correct by definition

Comment: @user40615 Yes, but then: what's wrong with the first method?

Comment: I didnt understand what you did with the first one

Comment: @user40615 I've edited it a little to clarify

Comment: If $r=(x, y, z)$, then $r\cdot r=x^2+y^2+z^2$ not $1$.

Comment: @user40615 $\hat r $ is a unit vector, so: $\hat r \cdot \hat r$=1 (vectors are parallel, and both have length 1 because they are unit vectors)

Comment: It looks as if you are only considering one axis in the first attempt. In $\mathbb{R}^n$, $\nabla\cdot\vec{r}=n$.

Comment: @robjohn let's pose it differently: apperantly: $\nabla \cdot \vec r= \frac{1}{r^2 }\frac{\partial}{\partial r} (r^2 v_r ).$ How would I get that result?

Comment: @user104662: If $v_r=r$ (i.e. the radial component of the radial function $\vec{r}$), then $\frac1{r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}(r^3)=\frac1{r^2}3r^2=3$.

Comment: @robjohn the $r$th component of a vector $\vec v$

Answer (score 2):

The first method you use is not complete. Notation $\nabla_r$ is only a scalar derivative operator and thus there's no definition of $\nabla\cdot~$ . What you want is actually the divergence in spherical coordinate, which can be written as
$$\nabla\cdot\vec u:=\frac1{r^2}\frac\partial{\partial r}(r^2u_r)+\frac1{r\sin\theta}\frac\partial{\partial\theta}(\sin\theta u_\theta)+\frac1{r\sin\theta}\frac{\partial u_\varphi}{\partial\varphi}$$
Thus
$$\nabla\cdot\vec r:=\frac1{r^2}\frac{\partial r^3}{\partial r}=3$$
which is the same as that in rectangular coordinate.

Comment: Yes that what I noticed as well (see my comment). But then: how would you derive your expression for the divergence? Or in what way does it make sense to remember it?

Comment: @user104662 It's just change of variables using chain rule.

Comment: Can you please show me how you obtain it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user104662 Well, that'll be lengthy. Let me explain in polar coordinate $(r,\theta)$. Known $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, it's direct to write $\frac{\partial}{\partial r}=\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial y}{\partial r}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$. Others are similar.

Comment: How is this related to the divergence that we are looking for?

Comment: @user104662 $div u=\partial_x u_x+\partial_y u_y$, then replace $\partial_x,\partial_y$ by $\partial_r,\partial_\theta$ will obtain divergence in polar coordinate.